# How can I return an array of bids made by the current user

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nosql

I have a collection of adverts, inside that there is a array of objects of bids made by other users to that specific advert. 
The thing I want to return is only the bids made by the current user so it has to match with `req.user.id` (where i hold the jwt token) 
So I tried filter method but it returned an empty array, then tried with for in loop, got another empty set of square brackets...

Here is my 'adverts' collection; 
For example, from the collection below, i want to get an array of objects only contains bids 
 made by this user (user : 5f7c40a0ec1a374c6c924610).

```
[
{
    "_id": "5f7d924371469c21f866fa16",
    "user": "5f7c40a0ec1a374c6c924610",
    "title": "Logistics for carrying chemicals",
    "text": "We need a approximately 20 trucks of logistics line for carrying our chemicals",
    "status": false,
    "company": "Bayrak Company",
    "location": "San Francisco",
    "date": "2020-10-07T10:02:43.811Z",
    "bids": [
        {
            "_id": "5f7dc3225a835c359432ab15",
            "user": "5f7c40a0ec1a374c6c924610",
            "bid": "50000",
            "company": "Bayrak Company",
            "avatar": "https://gravatar.com/avatar/4ecfd3d216693adc6867bf09c9087b1a?d=mm&r=pg&s=200",
            "date": "2020-10-07T13:31:14.890Z"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f7db5fea762d34054072f8c",
            "user": "5f7c40a0ec1a374c6c924610",
            "bid": "50000",
            "company": "Bayrak Company",
            "avatar": "https://gravatar.com/avatar/4ecfd3d216693adc6867bf09c9087b1a?d=mm&r=pg&s=200",
            "date": "2020-10-07T12:35:10.237Z"
        }
    ],
    "comments": [],
    "__v": 2
},
{
    "_id": "5f7db0153870fd4178390a4d",
    "user": "5f7c40a0ec1a374c6c924610",
    "title": "Need construction trucks for new buildings",
    "text": "The new constrution area needs approximately 15 trucks",
    "status": false,
    "company": "Bayrak Company",
    "location": "San Francisco",
    "date": "2020-10-07T12:09:57.362Z",
    "bids": [],
    "comments": [],
    "__v": 0
}
]
```

**And here is what I tried so far; **

```
// @route   GET /api/adverts/mybids
// @desc    Get bids that I made
// @access  Private.
router.get('/mybids', auth, async (req, res) => {
 try {
let adverts = await Advert.find();

 
let mybids = [];
let bidsByMe = [];
for (let x in adverts) {
  let bid = adverts[x].bids;

  for (let y in bid) {
    let innerBid = bid[y];
    mybids.push(innerBid);
  }
}

for (let x in mybids) {
  let bid = mybids[x];

  if (bid.user == req.user.id) {
    bidsByMe.push(bid);
  }
}

res.json(bidsByMe);
} catch (err) {
console.error(err.message);
res.status(500).send('Server Error...');
}
});
```

Comment: Use for instance `adverts.filter(ad => ad.bids.some(bid => bid.user == "..."))` to get all ads containing a bid by the user. The main problem with your current code is that you keep changing and pushing a single object into the array; you need to create a new bid object, populate and push it each time you find one.

Comment: I realized there is a logic missing... so here is a quick update

Comment: Don't put code in comments. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64245817/edit) the question instead.

Comment: just fixed that also. Now the thing is in my Advert schema typeof user is an ObjectId, on the other hand req.user.id is a string so i converted it into a string but it still goes to else condition

Comment: Why would you use `JSON.stringify()` there? `bid.user` is a string, not an object. Anyway, the first order of debugging is to `console.log()` *everything*.

Comment: I checked my Advert schema, inside 'bids' array, field of 'user' is an ObjectId, therefore I converted it. At the beginning of the question the reason was one of them was object, other one was a string

Comment: An object id is something like `"5f7c40a0ec1a374c6c924610"`, i.e. a string.

Comment: but `console.log(typeof bid.user)` returns object in the console other hand `console.log(typeof req.user.id)` returns string

Comment: Ok, but if `bid.user` is populated and therefore contains the user object, then stringifing it will not give you an id string you can compare to `req.user.id`. You'd have to do `if (bis.user._id == req.user.id)` instead.

Comment: The thing is that all this is basically moot, because like Kuldeep says, the database should support a query that already returns exactly what you want.

Comment: Just like you said a basic `==` solved the issue... Also yes the database supports that. Thank you for your answers. Sometimes the solution is just in front of our nose but we dont notice it... I will update the code. Code updated

Answer (score 0):

You can run this query :

```
  db.collection.aggregate([
 {
   $match: {
  user: "5f7c40a0ec1a374c6c924610",
  "bids.user": "5f7c40a0ec1a374c6c924610"
 }
},
{
$group: {
  _id: "$_id",
  user: {$first: "$user"},
  title: {$first: "$title"},
  text: {$first: "$text"},
  status: {$first: "$status"},
  location: {$first: "$location"},
  bids:{$first:"$bids"}
  
  }
}
 ])

//check below URL 

https://mongoplayground.net/p/TBGPDXO5lIl
```

Comment: That also returned fields like "comments" , "company" ... how do I ignore rest ?

Comment: updated the query please check and you can check result below given URL